# How does send work in flask-socketio?

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I cannot understand how `send` function works in `flask-socketio`.

For example, I am using `flask-socketio` as server and `socket.io` as client:

server:

```
@socketio.on("test")
def handle_test():
    send("Wow")
```

client:

```
socket.emit('test', "", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I think I can get `data` from server side, but I'm wrong. I just get nothing.

I understand I can build a structure based on event. But I cannot understand how `send` works. Will it send response to client? If it will, how could I get that response? If it won't, what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest you use `emit()` instead of `send()`.

To send from client to server, use this:

```
socket.emit('test', {data: 'my data'});
```

On the server, you can receive the event and then emit back to the client:

```
@socketio.on('test')
def handle_test():
    emit('wow');
```

To receive this second emit on the client, do this:

```
socket.on('wow', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I totally understand how `emit` works. In fact, that's what I have said "build a structure based on event". But I cannot figure out how `send` works. That is my question. Could you give more information about `send`?

Comment: `send()` is a legacy method, from older versions of Socket.IO. It uses two predefined event names `message` and `json` depending on the data being a string or a list/dict. So to receive from `send()` you would need to have an event handler for `message` on the other side.

Comment: Thank you, that make sense.